# Typescript Regex Extension methods

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

```
export class Regex { 
    public static readonly BLANK = /^\s+$/;
    public static readonly DIGITS = /^[0-9]*$/;
}
```

How can I create extension methods for Regex Class? I want to use Regex.Blank.toString() where required

Comment: If you want the regular expression by `toString` method, then there is already one property in `RegExp` class called `source`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
interface RegExpConstructor {
    readonly BLANK: RegExp;
    readonly DIGITS: RegExp;
}

if (RegExp.BLANK === undefined) {
    (RegExp as any).BLANK = /^\s+$/;
}

if (RegExp.DIGITS === undefined) {
    (RegExp as any).DIGITS = /^[0-9]*$/;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20RegExpConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20BLANK%3A%20RegExp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20DIGITS%3A%20RegExp%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aif%20(RegExp.BLANK%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(RegExp%20as%20any).BLANK%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5Cs%2B%24%2F%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aif%20(RegExp.DIGITS%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(RegExp%20as%20any).DIGITS%20%3D%20%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D*%24%2F%3B%0A%7D))

Note that there's a need to cast to `any` because you wanted the new properties to be `readonly`.
Also, I used `RegExpConstructor` instead of `RegExp` because you wanted the props to be static and not on instances.

As @SayanPal commented, `RegExp` instances have the `source` property which returns a string representation of the pattern, if you still want it as a `toString` then you can do this:

```
RegExp.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.source;
}
```